# I can not refer to the SharedPreferences from my module

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I created a module in my project. This module has a name "Connector". Now I create in MainActivity

```
    private SharedPreferences sPref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and fill data.

```
editor.putString("sessionId", user.getSession().getSession());
        editor.putString("userUuid", user.getUuid());
        editor.apply();
```

Now I need to take the data from the `SharedPreferences`  in my module "Connector". the problem is that the module "Connector" connects to the application

```
 compile project(':connector')
```

and classes that are in it, do not have access to classes that are in the project. how do I solve it?

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile project(':balanced-android')
    compile project(':connector')
}
```

Comment: Add more code pls because I don't know how you initiate the `editor` or `sPref`

Comment: can you share your settings.gradle file?

Comment: The point is not how to use SharedPreferences. and how to get them out of the underlying module

Answer (score 0):

The getPreferences retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to your activity MainActivity. This simply calls the underlying getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's class name as the preferences name.

You can use getSharedPreferences.

Read more at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper use of shared preferences is like this :

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences("any string", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

and you have to initialize the editor like :

editor = preferences.edit();

and after putting values inside editor you have to commit the editor:

editor.commit();

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

May you can use following

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String value = sharedPreferences.getString("userUuid","")
```